Unable to authorize API of a service using another authorization service
This is the error "Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext"

[!image of log]

//JwtAuthFilter.java
package com.example.application_service.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final String AUTH_SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/validate-token";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            ResponseEntity<String> authResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(AUTH_SERVICE_URL + "?token=" + jwtToken, String.class);

            if (authResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                // Token is valid; continue processing
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid Token");
            }
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Missing Token");
        }
    }
}

//SecurityConfig.java

package com.example.application_service.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        auth -> auth
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/applications/*", "/api/v1/feedback/*").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

}

//Logic of validating JWT token
@GetMapping("/validate-token")
    public ResponseEntity<?> validateToken(@RequestParam String token){
        if (jwtUtil.validateToken(token)) {
            System.out.println("Token is valid");
            String username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse("Token is valid", username));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid token");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Invalid token");
        }
    }

Please I  am unable to solve this problem. SecurityContext is getting set to anonymous SecurityContext and there not able to access the entry point.
I was trying to authenticate the API endpoint of one service using an Authorization service but even after getting authorization from the auth service the API endpoint is not accessible. I have added the image of the logs.
